# InvalidTokenException was unhandled by user code - "Unauthorized"

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

This is my code:

```
string accessToken = "##";
```

string accessTokenSecret = "##";
string consumerKey = "##";
string consumerSecret = "##";
string appToken = "##";
string realmId = "##"; //company id in quickbooks online

OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, appToken, realmId, IntuitServicesType.QBO);

I am receiving: **InvalidTokenException was unhandled by user code - {"Unauthorized"}**
in the creating the new ServiceContext line.  Not sure what the problem is.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Are you sure your OAuth tokens and keys are correct for the given realm you're trying to connect to?

Comment: I was able to connect.  I suspect it was related to the number of seconds I was setting for the Access Token Duration being set on the Intuit Anywhere Developer Playground page.  Is the only way to test/develop to open/establish a connection through the Playground first, so it generates the Access Token/Access Token Secret?  Does this connection need to stay alive as I develop and test the .Net application?

Comment: No, just set up your own OAuth components so that you can get your own OAuth token/token secret. The ones you get via OAuth will be valid for 6 months.

Comment: Last question (I hope) - is there documentation available that walks through setting up your own OAuth components?

Comment: This is the only thing Intuit has released that I'm aware of: http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App   We have docs/examples for PHP, beyond what I posted above, I'm not aware of anything else Intuit has released. With that said, it's standard OAuth, so any OAuth tutorial you can find for your language should work.

Comment: If you reponse to this question, in a form of an answer, I can mark your response as an answer to my question.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message:

> InvalidTokenException was unhandled by user code - {"Unauthorized"}

Occurs when the OAuth tokens you're using are no longer valid.

I would double-check that:

- You're using a valid set of OAuth tokens that you got from Intuit
- The tokens are not expired (the Developer Playground tokens are very
  short lived, longer-lived 6-month tokens are available if you set up
  your own actual OAuth endpoint)

Here is Intuit's documentation for setting up your own OAuth endpoint:

- http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App